# What happens to data in a GCP project if all owners or the project itself is suspended?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, disaster-recovery

I have realized recently that a personal domain on google apps for business got suspended (the free for life version that was available in beta). This actually happened like 6 months ago and I didn't notice because I haven't used for years since the domain itself was a gaming nickname. I know it didn't expire because I never got an alert and they used to send those.

I couldn't care less about it but it made me realize that on our disaster recovery scenarios we never accounted for losing access to our project due to some false positive.

We replicate some of our data across services (aws to gcp and gcp to aws) for HA reasons, but we definitely have some blind spots. We also have several owners on our projects, so someone losing their account isn't going to leave us in the dirt, but **what if the project itself or every owner is flagged, what happens with the drives? snapshots? buckets? do you suddenly lose access to everything?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Project can be suspended due to [ToS](https://cloud.google.com/terms/) violations and when that happens all the existing workloads are shut down and users lose access to the project. However, there is a notification sent to the project owner to fix the violation and after that you should be able to access your project again and start up your resources. It is possible that your account has a grace period in which you can still recover your data, but if you are over the grace period time your data might be unrecoverable.

But your case is that your GSuite free trial was suspended, in that case you should review as well the [ToS](https://gsuite.google.com/intl/en_in/terms/2013/1/premier_terms.html) to know the reason for your suspension. Otherwise, it may worth open a case [here](https://gsuite.google.com/support/) and see if you can recover the access to it.

Comment: I don't need to recover the account I mentioned. This question is not about that.

Comment: If you lose access to the project and resources are shut down, then that means there's no way to access your data or transfer it to another provider while you appeal, is that correct?

Comment: Yes, while you appeal is in process you will not able to access your resources

Comment: Just accepted your answer. Do you have any sources or is this experience from using their services?

Comment: You can take a look on this [document](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/project-suspension-guidelines) for GCP project suspension guidelines.